# Transform the dataframe from long to wide using pandas - Single row output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
'date':['2173/04/11','2173/04/12','2173/04/11','2173/04/12','2173/05/14','2173/05/15','2173/05/14','2173/05/15'],
'time_1':['2173/04/11 12:35:00','2173/04/12 12:50:00','2173/04/11 12:59:00','2173/04/12 13:14:00','2173/05/14 13:37:00','2173/05/15 13:39:00','2173/05/14 18:37:00','2173/05/15 19:39:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,40,40,7,7,38,38],
 'iid' :[12,12,12,12,21,21,21,21]   
 })
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
```

I tried using `stack,unstack,pivot and melt` approach but doesn't seem to help

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars =['subject_id','val'], value_vars =['date','val']) #1

df.unstack().reset_index()  #2

df.pivot(index='subject_id', columns='time_1', values='val')  #3
```

I expect my output dataframe to look like as shown below

[image]

**updated screenshot**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create helper Series by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with same column/columns for new index - here `subject_id`, create `MultiIndex`, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last flatten `MulitIndex in columns`:

```
cols = ['time_1','val']
df = df.set_index(['subject_id', df.groupby('subject_id').cumcount().add(1)])[cols].unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   subject_id             time_11             time_12             time_13  \
0           1 2173-04-11 12:35:00 2173-04-12 12:50:00 2173-04-11 12:59:00   
1           2 2173-05-14 13:37:00 2173-05-15 13:39:00 2173-05-14 18:37:00   

              time_14  val1  val2  val3  val4  
0 2173-04-12 13:14:00     5     5    40    40  
1 2173-05-15 19:39:00     7     7    38    38
```

Missing values are expected, if not same number of `id` groups - `unstack` use max count and then are added misisng values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,2,2,3],
'date':['2173/04/11','2173/04/12','2173/04/11','2173/04/12','2173/05/14','2173/05/15'],
'time_1':['2173/04/11 12:35:00','2173/04/12 12:50:00','2173/04/11 12:59:00',
          '2173/04/12 13:14:00','2173/05/14 13:37:00','2173/05/15 13:39:00'],
 'val' :[5,5,40,40,7,7],
 'iid' :[12,12,12,12,21,21]   
 })
df['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_1'])
df['day'] = df['time_1'].dt.day
print (df)
   subject_id        date              time_1  val  iid  day
0           1  2173/04/11 2173-04-11 12:35:00    5   12   11
1           1  2173/04/12 2173-04-12 12:50:00    5   12   12
2           1  2173/04/11 2173-04-11 12:59:00   40   12   11
3           2  2173/04/12 2173-04-12 13:14:00   40   12   12
4           2  2173/05/14 2173-05-14 13:37:00    7   21   14
5           3  2173/05/15 2173-05-15 13:39:00    7   21   15
```

---

```
cols = ['time_1','val']
df = df.set_index(['subject_id', df.groupby('subject_id').cumcount().add(1)])[cols].unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   subject_id             time_11             time_12             time_13  \
0           1 2173-04-11 12:35:00 2173-04-12 12:50:00 2173-04-11 12:59:00   
1           2 2173-04-12 13:14:00 2173-05-14 13:37:00                 NaT   
2           3 2173-05-15 13:39:00                 NaT                 NaT   

   val1  val2  val3  
0   5.0   5.0  40.0  
1  40.0   7.0   NaN  
2   7.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Wow. I see that you always have solution for problems of varying complexities. fantastic. Only thing is sometimes, I take too much of time to understand your solution. I execute line by line. Your explanation also helps

Comment: However, one quick question. I see lot of columns with NA's. Updated the screeshot in post.

Comment: I have only 4 date values as shown in sample dataframe. I was expecting to see only `date1,date2,date3,date4`. Don't know why columns are upto `8`.

Comment: My subject_id appears only 4 times. So cumcount is also only upto 4 but finally it is 8

Comment: @SSMK - I think there is at least one non missing row (first), added change sample data for see it.

Comment: Actually I am fine if there is `NaT` in first 4 columns. But how does it generate `date5,date6,date7,date8`.?

Comment: All columns go upto number 8. Like `val8`, `item_name8` etc. Shouldn't it be just 4?

Comment: @SSMK hmmm, I think there is at least one groups with `8` values, you can check it by `print (df['subject_id'].value_counts())`